# Url and Site Structure for State/City Directory

Tags: url, seo, directory, schema

I am creating a national directory for a niche service.  Im thinking the structure should be broken down in one of two formats, but im open to suggestions.

site.com/category/subcategory/state/city

or

site.com/state/city/category/subcategory

which one of the above would work the best? Or, is there another that will work better?

Answer (score 0):

If every state has its own different categories and subcategories you definately go for this one: 
site.com/state/city/category/subcategory

If your categories are in general for all states you go for the second one.

This approach absolutely makes sense, and you avoid getting your visitors confused.